# Function to fill linked list but for n lists types

Tags: c, list, struct

So what I want is to do a function that given a node it puts it in the last place. The thing is I want to do a function that works with all of my list structures. How do I do this? So far I managed to make a function that puts a node in last but only for one type of list. Here is the code:

```
void putList(PESPECIALIDADE *p){
    int i = 1;
    p->proximo = NULL;
     ptr;
    if(cabecaEspecialidade == NULL){
        p->id=1;
        cabecaEspecialidade = p;
    }
    else{
        for(ptr=cabecaEspecialidade; ptr->proximo != NULL; ptr = ptr->proximo){
            i++;
        }
        p->id=i+1;
        ptr->proximo = p;
        p->proximo=NULL;            
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `ptr`? Where do you declare it? What is `PESPECIALIDADE`? Do your lists have any common base structure?

Comment: Please show the main code.

Comment: I would approach it the other way around - instead of trying to make code that works to everything I would create a list that can be added (easily) to any object. Hopefully I'll time later to write a real answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have many lists of different contents, a common way is to have a common node structure as base for all lists.

```
struct base_node
{
    struct base_node *next;
};
```

Then you have that structure *first* in all other structures used for your lists:

```
struct some_node_data
{
    struct base_node node;  /* Note: not a pointer */

    /* All other data... */
};
```

(Note: Having the base node structure as a member in the new structure, it's kind of like C++ inheritance.)

Now you can cast a pointer to the above structure as a pointer to the `base_node` structure, and use that.

```
void add_tail(struct base_node **head, struct base_node *node)
{
    /* Add `node` at the end of the list pointed to by `*head` */
}

/* ... */

struct some_node_data *some_data_head = NULL;

struct some_node_data *some_node = malloc(sizeof struct some_node_data);
add_tail((struct base_node *) &some_data_head, (struct base_node *) some_node);
```

Comment: why do i have to do this line ? : (struct base_node *) some_node when calling the function?

Comment: @RicardoSacramento Because while the `some_node_data` structure in a way inherits from the `base_node` structure, they are different types and you need to explicitly typecast the pointer.